# To give a talk?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

What is the most appropriate verb to use with "talk" in the sense of "an informal address or lecture":

- "To **give** a talk"?
- "To **present** a talk"?
- "To **deliver** a talk"?
- Another completely different verb or phrase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I think **present a talk** sounds seriously wrong. Gibberish, to be honest. But apparently it does occur. Not so often as **deliver a talk**, which I have no problem with apart from the obvious fact that it's not what we normally say (to wit, **give a talk**, which is overwhelmingly the standard turn of phrase)...[image]

This graph is from Google's [NGram Viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=give%20a%20talk,deliver%20a%20talk,present%20a%20talk&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which indexes all the words in millions of books - including many written hundreds of years ago, as well as publications from recent decades. To give some idea of the actual numbers involved, **give a talk** appears about 5000 times in books published between 1995 and 2000 whereas **present a talk** only occurs about 250 times.

Comment: *Deliver a talk* is probably due to *deliver a speech*.

Comment: @Cerberus: Sounds convincing to me. Always assuming that "is due to..." is a euphemism for "is caused by ignorant bowlderisation of...". But "present a talk" is, well, just daft. :)

Comment: But you can also "make a presentation" or "present a paper". So you get 16 choices: make/present/deliver/give a speech/presentation/paper/talk, of which maybe 7 are correct. No wonder these get confounded.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Can you please make some explaining comments on your diagram? Where does the data come from?

Comment: @Rasmus: I've added a note about how I created the chart. Including a link to NGram so you can go look for yourself if you want.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I doubt anyone *presents a presentation** except facetiously, so that's one combination easily ruled out. Personally I think there's something 'tautological' about **present a talk**, on top of which *presentation* implies a visual element that mightn't be there in a *talk*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I [checked Ngrams,](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=give+a+speech%2Cdeliver+a+speech%2Cgive+a+talk%2Cmake+a+presentation%2Cgive+a+presentation%2Cpresent+a+paper&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and the most common phrase (dwarfing everything else) is *make a speech*. But people also commonly *give* or *deliver* speeches, *make* presentations, *give* talks, and *present* papers. People used not to *give* presentations, but that's catching up recently. All other combinations were rare. Why can people make speeches but not talks? I don't know.

Comment: @Peter Shor: That's rather interesting. I felt already that *give* would be 'relatively' new, which is why I graphed from 1900 in the first place. But of course *make a speech* is more national newspapers reporting on politicians' activities, where *give a talk* suggests a report in the village magazine about something at the local Women's Institute weekly meeting. So you'd prolly get more of the former in NGrams simply because that kind of stuff makes it into NGrams corpus.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: to present a paper means to talk about the paper (it can be shortened or the presentation can actually be longer, with detailed examples) - main point is that the content of the speech and the paper are different; otherwise you could say 'let me read you my paper' or you could tell them to read it themselves. Therefore to present a talk would make sense only in very specific context; for example assume you have prepared a talk that is a highlight of your career - then you might present it to your friends before you actually deliver it (still there are better phrases).

Comment: @Unreason: I think I agree with everything you and @Peter Shor say. There *are* possible meanings and contexts for many less-common permutations. But I'm guessing they don't apply in OP's circumstances, which are probably just the normal ones.

Answer (score 1):

The first would be the most informal of the three (though not actually "informal" per se), and probably suits your needs.

"Presenting" a talk is less common than "giving" a talk, and would only be used if there was a presentation associated with the talk.

Lastly, "Delivering" a talk is definitely the more formal than "giving" a talk, probably due to the fact that "delivering" something is always more impersonal than "giving" it.